# Split Time Hourly for Tasks and duration

Tags: vba, loops, do-while

I have the following data set and I have been trying to split the start and finish hourly, but so far using Loop I have reached no solution

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5J7N.png)

The result should be something like this (and so on for the other tasks), but i have been having trouble from one day to another, past midnight

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mI13.png)

I would appreciate any help, kinda new to vba and my code was really simple just looping on a column with the hour value but not using the date value, which stops working when there are more than a day interval between start and end of each task.

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure if you were doing the editing in place or making a new page with the adjusted values.  This version makes the change in place.

```
Sub split_times()
    Const start_col = 1
    Dim col As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' process the active sheet
    'Set s = Worksheets("sheet1") ' process a particualr sheet
    row = 2
    Do Until s.Cells(row, start_col).Value = ""
        Debug.Print s.Cells(row, start_col).Value
        Do While s.Cells(row, start_col + 4) > 1
            s.Rows(row).Insert
            s.Cells(row, start_col).Value = s.Cells(row + 1, start_col).Value ' task ID
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 1).Value = s.Cells(row + 1, start_col + 1).Value ' task name
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 2).Value = CDate(s.Cells(row + 1, start_col + 2).Value) ' task Start
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 3).Value = DateAdd("h", 1, CDate(s.Cells(row, start_col + 2).Value))  ' task finish
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 4).Value = 1  ' duration
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 5).Value = s.Cells(row + 1, start_col + 5).Value ' C1
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 6).Value = s.Cells(row + 1, start_col + 6).Value ' C2
            
            ' adjust remaining data
            row = row + 1
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 2).Value = s.Cells(row - 1, start_col + 3).Value ' task start
            s.Cells(row, start_col + 4).Value = s.Cells(row, start_col + 4).Value - 1 ' duration
        
        Loop
        row = row + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```